# Setting headers in Twitter API POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am attempting to use the POST statuses/update Twitter API call. I'm new to this so please bear with me :). As outlined in this [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) I've been trying to set up headers to use application only authentication.

What I have tried so far is as follows:

```
    $(".tweet-later").on("click", function(event){
    $.ajax({
         url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json",
         data: { status: "Testing"},
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         beforeSend: function(xhr){
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Rm5DVHpIc2M2ejRpeDRQRDRdfdsjprbjB5TENzeEZQNnhza2NFMzB6dnJMbnI2aENlRUZSczdOZUtWZUhaREhXSFVCY3dQWA==');
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
         },
         success: function(data) { alert('Tweeted!'); },
        error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
      });
  });
```

I keep receiving an error: "Authentication Failed".All help is very much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: When hitting application only enpoints such as `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json`, the Authorization header must contain `Bearer`. In your case the endpoint you're sending a request to does not accept application only auth, however if it did setting the auth header you would like the following: 
`xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer Rm5DVHpIc2M2ejRpeDRQRDRdfdsjprbjB5TENzeEZQNnhza2NFMzB6dnJMbnI2aENlRUZSczdOZUtWZUhaREhXSFVCY3dQWA==');`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible.

As it says [in the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only):

> When issuing requests using application-only auth, there is no concept of a “current user.” Therefore, endpoints such as POST statuses / update will not function with application-only auth. See using OAuth for more information for issuing requests on behalf of a user.